# Get value a method was called with during unit test

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, pytest-mock

I am using `pytest_mock` to mock a function call. I would like to inspect the call to `doB()` to see if it was called with the value 3. How would I write the assert for this?

```
def testtest(mocker):
    # arrange
    mocker.patch.object(ClassA, 'doB', return_value=None)
    sut = ClassA()
    # act
    actual = sut.party(4) # will make a call to doB
    expected = 3
    # assert
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
def testtest(mocker):
    # arrange
    mocked_doB = mocker.patch.object(ClassA, 'doB', return_value=None)
    sut = ClassA()
    # act
    actual = sut.party(4) # will make a call to doB
    expected = 3
    # assert
    mocked_doB.assert_called_once_with(expected)
```

If you assign a value to the mocked object, in this case variable `mocked_doB`, you will get a `MagicMock` object back. With this MagicMock object, you have access to all kind of methods from the `unittest.mock` Mock class, e.g.

- assert_called_once_with()
- call_count,
- and many more...

See here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class

This works because with the pytest-mock framework you can directly access the `mock` module from `mocker`.
This is stated here under "Usage", https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.